# where can I find android pinpoint icon

Tags: android, google-maps, icons, android-drawable

Hi I wan't to add pinpoints to a google map, and I would like to use something similar to the standard red or blue pinpoint icon like in this image: http://www.imapbuilder.com/images/online-builder/thumb/categorize-pinpoints-with-icon.png. Is such an icon available in the android.R.drawable? what is it called? how can I get it (or a similar one) otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is such an icon available in the android.R.drawable?

No, because Google Maps are not part of the standard Android SDK.

> how can I get it (or a similar one) otherwise?

There are many, many free clipart libraries available on the Internet -- find an image that you like with license terms that you like. Or, have a graphic artist create one.

Note that Maps V2's has a default marker which resembles the blue one in your image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe V1 of the Maps add-on included markers by default (you had to supply your own), but V2 does.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker

If you're using V1 you can get some here: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/